# ng-model not working with md-menu angularjs material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, ng-controller

I am using md-menu from angular material and in the list I have attached a search box with ng-model. But I am unable to access ng-model because of 'md-menu-content' is out of scope. my code is here:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <md-menu style="margin:auto 0;" md-position-mode="target-right target" md-offset="-40 0">
          <md-button ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="list">
            <i class="material-icons" md-menu-origin style="color:#006487;">&#xE8B6;</i>
          </md-button>
          <md-menu-content width="4">
              <md-menu-item>
                <input autofocus type="search" placeholder="Search in Line Items" id="table-search-inp" aria-label="search for line item" ng-model="searchLineItemText" ng-model-options="{ debounce: {default: 500} }" />
              </md-menu-item>
          </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
</div>
```

and Controller:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('myController', myController);
QuoteLineItemController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
function QuoteLineItemController($scope, $rootScope){
$scope.searchLineItemText = '';
$scope.$watch('searchLineItemText', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue) {
        fetchSearchedLineItems(newValue);
      }
    });
};
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

Please add angular material dependency.

```
QuoteLineItemController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
```

to

```
QuoteLineItemController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope','ngMaterial'];
```

Check with this. [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/d3zExiS03YNOMLHdfEIj/preview)
You need to add library also.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Sorry, I added ngMaterial also. everything is working perfect, except md-menu.

Comment: the problem is md-menu content elements appended the end of body in html.